# Why is the last parameter of a function is not getting its value?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I spent lot time to figure out this issue on production environment. On QA, UAT and DEV environment this is working fine. It seems something is related to server. Below are the details which I did.

I added on more field to an existing function with default value and tested with both NULL and '' as default value.

```
    public function test($a, $b, $c = '')
    public function test($a, $b, $c = NULL)
```

When I am calling this function, the last argument is not getting its value. When I print the arguments in the log file, I am getting the default value for last parameter i.e. NULL instead of actual value. I am using Zend framework 1.

Below is the code to to write the arguments to log file. I added below the line in the start of the function.

```
     $arg_list = func_get_args();
     Sg_Log_Manager::info(print_r($arg_list , true));
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: you need to show HOW you're calling the functions...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your description you mention a default value of NULL but in your source code you have a default value of empty string ''. That's something different!

The documentation for `func_get_args()` states:

*This function returns a copy of the passed arguments only, and does not account for default (non-passed) arguments.*

Comment: but I am passing all parameters with hard coded while calling test function.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but I just tested with both NULL value and empty string '' and found not working